# Nested list JSON .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I am currently trying to accept a `POST` request to a .NET Core Web API endpoint that accepts the following model:

```
public class OrderPost
{
    [Required]
    public string DeliveryStreet { get; set; }

    public string DeliveryBuilding { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DeliveryCity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DeliveryProvince { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DeliveryPostalCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CardName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CardExpiry { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long CardCvv { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Uri ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public long Price { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; } 
    public DateTimeOffset UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public long Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

When I remove the `List<OrderItem>` and post the data without the List the call works perfectly. As soon as I add the list back and try and `POST` the data I get a `400 Bad Request` error. I have a feeling I am just missing some attribute or something on the List. The JSON I am posting is valid, I double checked that. Any ideas of what could be causing this?

Here is the JSON I am POST'ing:

```
{
    "deliveryStreet": "Test street",
    "deliveryBuilding": "",
    "deliveryCity": "TEst",
    "deliveryProvince": "TEst",
    "deliveryPostalCode": "0852",
    "cardName": "Jane Jones",
    "cardNumber": "4711 1000 0000 0000",
    "cardExpiry": "05 / 20",
    "cardCvv": "123",
    "orderItems": [{
        "id": 1,
        "category": null,
        "name": "Test",
        "description": "Test test test",
        "imageUrl": "http://google.com/",
        "price": 625,
        "createdAt": "2019-02-21T13:25:56.709192",
        "updatedAt": "2019-02-21T13:25:56.709192",
        "quantity": 5
    }]
}
```

Here is the Endpoint that I am trying to `POST` to:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]OrderPost data)
{
        //Get the credit card type off of the number
        var type = StringUtilities.GetCardTypeFromNumber(data.CardNumber);
        //Check if valid type was found
        if (type == "UNKNOWN")
            return BadRequest("Unknown credit card type");

        float total = 0;
        .................
}
```

Comment: What do your server logs say? You should be able to find some information as to why a 400 is triggered.

Comment: 400 means the *request* was bad. It's nor related to JSON serialization. You haven't posted any server-side code or an example of the request, or even an example of the JSON string so it's not possible to help. Check your web server's logs, use your browser's Development Tools or a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what's actually sent to the server.

Comment: @Tachyon Have you tried debugging that code? What happened? What do the output window says?

Comment: @Tachyon again, check your browsers logs and use Fiddler to see what's being sent. `400` means the request never made it to the action. The server itself rejected it as a Bad Request. Perhaps the content type is wrong? How did you make the request?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Or the request made it: `return BadRequest("Unknown credit card type");` OR the request made it and the ModelState validation done by the new ASP.NET Core WebAPI attribute was not successful

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - It doesn't trigger the breakpoint in the method. The only thing in the output window is: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 234.6575ms 400 application/problem+json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: @Tachyon your *own code* is returning a `BadRequest`. Are you sure that's not what's going on? What did Fiddler show?

Comment: @Tachyon You probably have log output level set to Information, move that to Trace

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I have a breakpoint above my own `BadRequest` it doesn't hit the breakpoint at all in the method.

Comment: @Tachyon what did Fiddler show? For all one knows, you may be runnin in Release mode. What does the raw response look like?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am `POST`'ing from an Ionic mobile app. The response it is getting back is as follows `{"status":400,"url":"https://192.168.1.134:45457/api/v1/store/Order","headers":{"date":"Thu, 21 Feb 2019 14:46:39 GMT","x-sourcefiles":"=","server":"Microsoft-IIS/10.0","okhttp-selected-protocol":"http/1.1","okhttp-response-source":"NETWORK 400","transfer-encoding":"chunked","x-powered-by":"ASP.NET","content-type":"application/problem+json; charset=utf-8","forwarded":"host=192.168.1.134:45457; proto=https"},"error":""}` As you can see the error is empty

Comment: Try to change `Uri ImageUrl` to `string ImageUrl`. I'm not sure the serializer can convert a string to a Uri automatically

Comment: I've tried changing it to a `string` - makes no difference unfortunately

Comment: Seems like its a serialization issue with your OrderItem type. I noticed you are sending long CardCvv with quotes "123" but not using quotes in your list items' longs. Did you try with quotes? eg.  "price": "625"

Comment: @Tachyon what if you make all properties of OrderItem class strings (no DatetimeOffsets, no Uris, no longs)? Does it still fail?

Comment: Still fails. I am starting to think the error is on the client side and not on the server side to be honest.

Comment: What is the content of your `404` response?

Comment: What is your .net core version?

Comment: @Tachyon did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

How about you send ?

```
data: {
   deliveryObj: yourDeilveryObj,
   orderItems: yourOrderItemsArray
}
```

And your `json` obj should look like the following:

```
{   
    "deliveryObj":      
        {   
            "deliveryStreet": "Test street",
            "deliveryBuilding": "",
            "deliveryCity": "TEst",
            "deliveryProvince": "TEst",
            "deliveryPostalCode": "0852",
            "cardName": "Jane Jones",
            "cardNumber": "4711 1000 0000 0000",
            "cardExpiry": "05 / 20",
            "cardCvv": "123",
        }, 

    "orderItems": [{
        "id": 1,
        "category": null,
        "name": "Test",
        "description": "Test test test",
        "imageUrl": "http://google.com/",
        "price": 625,
        "createdAt": "2019-02-21T13:25:56.709192",
        "updatedAt": "2019-02-21T13:25:56.709192",
        "quantity": 5
    }]
}
```

Now, at the backend, you should receive it as
`JObject`.

Your receiving method should look like this`Post(JObject objData)`. Now you can break down this `objData` to `JObject` and `JArray`.
It would look like something:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult POST(JObject objData)
        {

            dynamic jsonData = objData;

            //DeliveryObj
            JObject deliveryObjJson = jsonData.deliveryObj;
            var deliveryObj= deliveryObjJson .ToObject<OrderPost>();

            //OrderItemsArray
            JArray orderItemsJson = jsonData.orderItems;
            var orderItems = orderItemsJson.Select(item => item.ToObject<OrderItem>()).ToList();



            return Ok(_services.Post(deliveryObj, orderItems ).Data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Asp.Net Core Web api, Model validation errors automatically trigger an HTTP 400 response, check [Automatic HTTP 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#automatic-http-400-responses)
.

Try to make a test with code below:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
```