# Ionic can't post nested array

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ionic-framework

I posted the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809578/nested-list-json-net) question earlier and it would appear that there is nothing wrong with my API endpoint and that the error lies on the client side. I am trying to post data to the above mentioned API endpoint.

I am building up the JSON object as follows:

```
let data = {
      "deliveryStreet": this.formGroup.get('shippingLineOne').value,
      "deliveryBuilding": this.formGroup.get('shippingLineTwo').value,
      "deliveryCity": this.formGroup.get('shippingCity').value,
      "deliveryProvince": this.formGroup.get('shippingProvince').value,
      "deliveryPostalCode": this.formGroup.get('shippingPostalCode').value,
      "cardName": this.formGroup.get('cardholderName').value,
      "cardNumber": this.formGroup.get('ccNum').value,
      "cardExpiry": this.formGroup.get('ccExp').value,
      "cardCvv": this.formGroup.get('cardCvv').value,
      "orderItems": this.cart.cartItems
    };
```

Where `this.cart.cartItems` is an array of objects. I have tried to `JSON.stringify` both the array directly and the entire object before `POST`'ing but it doesn't make a difference. When I remove the `"orderItems": this.cart.cartItems` the `POST` is successful so I know it has something to do with the array.

I am `POST`'ing the data as follows:

```
//Set serializer
this.http.setDataSerializer('JSON');
this.http.setSSLCertMode('nocheck');

//Call the endpoint
let response = await this.http.post(`${API}/${endpoint}`, data, { 'Authorization': bearer });
```

Does anyone have any idea why I cannot `POST` the orderItems array in my JSON object?

Comment: `DateTimeOffset` doesn't appear to have a constructor that takes a string. I wonder if that might have something to do with it.,

Comment: Right, I figured it out. It's a problem with the underlying encryption of the app (hybrid: AES256-CBC and RSA-OAEP) if the string being parsed in the json array had a special character like some Norwegian style thing. It would corrupt the data. Rendering the json format invalid giving me the 400 errors. I do appreciate everyone's help with this though!